# Laravel 8 - Routing Problem - Missing Required Parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I have routing problem, that I can't seem to fix.

So first:
Here is a  dynamicly created buttons in my "languages.blade.php"

```
<a href="edit-keywords/{{ $language->language_code }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-language"></i>&nbsp; Edit Keywords</a>
```

Here is routing lines in my "web.php"

```
 Route::get('/admin/edit-keywords/{code}', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LanguageController::class, 'edit_keywords'])->name('admin.edit-keywords');
 Route::post('/admin/edit-keywords', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LanguageController::class, 'save_keywords'])->name('admin.save_keywords');
```

Here is public function in my "LanguageController.php"

```
public function edit_keywords($code){

   $language['view'] = Languages::getLanguage($code);
   $keyword['view'] =  Languages::getKeyword($code);
   $data = array('language' => $language, 'keyword' => $keyword);

   return view('admin.edit-keywords')->with($data);

}
```

And here is 2 functions in my languages model

```
  public static function getLanguage($code){

    $value=DB::table('languages')->where('language_code', '=', $code)->first();
    return $value;

  }

  public static function getKeyword($code){

     $value=DB::table('keywords')->where('language_code', $code)->orderBy('keyword_id', 'asc')->get();
     return $value;

  }
```

When I click on the button it brings me to link: `http://localhost/admin/edit-keywords/LV` so for routing it's all right.

But I get this error everytime and for every language:

> Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException

> Missing required parameter for [Route: admin.edit-keywords] [URI:admin/edit-keywords/{code}]

> [Missing parameter: code]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\resources\views\admin\edit-keywords.blade.php)

> http://localhost/admin/edit-keywords/LV

Edit:

Here it works:

```
Route::get('/admin/edit-language/{language_code}', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LanguageController::class, 'edit_language'])->name('admin.edit-language');
Route::post('/admin/edit-language', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LanguageController::class, 'update_language'])->name('admin.edit-language');
```

Comment: Do you have some dynamic `urls` in `edit-keywords.blade.php`?
Like: `<a href="edit-keywords/{{ $language->language_code }}" class...`

Comment: Yes, for example : <h1>Edit {{ $language['view']->language_name }} Language</h1>

Comment: @mare96 <input type="hidden" name="language_code" value="{{ $language['view']->language_code }}">

Comment: You are missing somewhere parameter `{code}` for your URL. Not for inputs or dynamic text. Just check URLs

Comment: Also, check your form method and route for submitting a form.

Comment: You should be using the `route()` helper with the route name to build URLs in your template. You may want to change the url in the future, and will not have to edit your templates. It also prevents typos, as an error is thrown when using an incorrect route name.

Comment: they are using the `route` helper to build a URL which is why they are getting the missing required parameter from the URL generator ... you have to actually show the code that is referenced in the error which is from `views\admin\edit-keywords.blade.php`, you are basically showing everything but the thing causing the error

Comment: @lagbox Here is place from where error comes ->   <h1>Edit {{ $language['view']->language_name }} Language</h1>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate everyone's help.

How it seams, since I upgraded to Laravel 8, there is different routing ways.

I found problem:
It was in "edit-keywords.blade.php"

I had to change

```
<form action="/admin/edit-keywords/" method="post" id="setting_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

To

```
 <form action="/admin/edit-keywords/{code}" method="post" id="setting_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

And route also

```
  Route::post('/admin/edit-keywords/', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LanguageController::class, 'save_keywords'])->name('admin.save_keywords');
```

Changed to

```
  Route::post('/admin/edit-keywords/{code}', [App\Http\Controllers\Admin\LanguageController::class, 'save_keywords'])->name('admin.save_keywords');
```

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use the route name as mentionned in [the official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#named-routes), and add your url parameter like this :

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.edit-keywords', $language->language_code) }}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-language"></i>&nbsp; Edit Keywords</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for advice, but it still doesn't fix anything. :(